# DocuSign API: upload NetSuite document to envelope

Tags: netsuite, docusignapi

I'm building a dynamic PDF in NetSuite.  I want to upload it to a new DocuSign envelope using the DocuSign REST API.  I've seen a lot of answers, but I'm missing something.  I'm finding myself running around in circles in the API and online.

In the DocuSign REST API for [creating Envelopes][1] it details how to add a document to an envelope, specifically using the documents node:

```
"documents": [{
    "documentId": "1",
    "name": "contract.pdf",
    "documentBase64": "base64 document bytes...",
}],
```

Is the "name" property the filepath where the document is located in my NetSuite directory?  Is it instead expecting the file to already be in the DocuSign document folder?  Needing to encode implies the former.  Using only a filename implies the latter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the `name` property within a `document` object in a **Create Envelope** request, you're specifying the name of the document as it'll appear within the Envelope. For example, the name of the document in the following screenshot is **dstest.txt** (as shown above the document thumbnail in the right pane).

[image: DS Envelope]

You should set the `documentBase64` property to the the base64-encoded string that represents the content of the file. That is, you'll do the following in your code:

- Read in the file from where ever it's stored.
- Create a string that represents the base64-encoded content of the file.
- Set the `documentBase64` property within the `document` object in the **Create Envelope** request to the base64-encoded string that represents the content of the file.